# Should you use Slack's Bolt Python SDK to handle OAuth installation flow?

Tags: authentication, oauth, slack, bolt

I am trying to develop a simple event-driven Slack bot that uses a user and a bot token to perform some authenticated API calls to Slack's Web API. The bot is functional, except I can't figure out how to use Bolt to store and manage the OAuth tokens after installation. This is my first time using OAuth, so apologies if I am missing anything obvious.

The best guidance I have found on using it is from this link: https://slack.dev/bolt-python/concepts#authenticating-oauth

However, I do not fully understand what an installation_store or state_store is, and more importantly, I am not sure how to access the stored tokens as needed. Furthermore, it seems like this solution relies on local persistence, but Heroku (where I deployed the bot) does not support that. I would prefer a cloud-based solution.

As a result, I decided to build a simple Flask app that handles the installation flow, making the authentication API call and storing the token(s) in a corresponding DynamoDB table. The tokens are stored as key-value pairs, with the key being either the team_id or the user_id, but I don't believe this works if one user uses the bot in multiple workspaces.

Furthermore, I feel like this solution is hacky and unmaintainble. What is the best way to handle the OAuth flow?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this question while trying to figure out the same myself. I can see that [slack_sdk](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-sdk/tree/main/slack_sdk/oauth/installation_store) does support other installation and state stores like sqllite, aws,... unsure why the same was not carried forward in bolt for python. Having this feature of other stores would be better for security.

So I might suggest using slack_sdk instead of slack_bolt for now?